# Optimize self join on millions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2012

I have a table which is a link table from objects in my SQL Server 2012 database, (`annonsid, annonsid2`). This table is used to create chains of triangle or even rectangles to see who can swap with who.

This is the query I use on the table `Matching_IDs` which has 1,5 million rows in it, producing 14 million possible chains using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Matching_IDs AS m
  INNER JOIN Matching_IDs AS m2
     ON m.annonsid2 = m2.annonsid
  INNER JOIN Matching_IDs AS m3
     ON m2.annonsid2 = m3.annonsid
       AND m.annonsid = m3.annonsid2
```

I must improve performance to take maybe 1 second or less, Is there a faster way to do this? The query takes about 1 minute on my computer. I normally use a `WHERE m.annonsid=x`, but it takes just the same amount of time, cause it has to go through all possible combinations anyway.

Update: the latest query plan

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[globalagg1011],0)))
   |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([globalagg1011]=SUM([partialagg1010])))
        |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
             |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([partialagg1010]=Count(*)))
                  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([m2].[annonsid2], [m2].[annonsid])=([m3].[annonsid], [m].[annonsid2]), RESIDUAL:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[annonsid2] as [m2].[annonsid2]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[annonsid] as [m3].[annonsid] AND [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[annonsid2] as [m].[annonsid2]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[annonsid] as [m2].[annonsid]))
                       |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([m2].[annonsid2], [m2].[annonsid]))
                       |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[NonClusteredIndex-20121229-133207] AS [m2]))
                       |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([m3].[annonsid], [m].[annonsid2]))
                            |--Merge Join(Inner Join, MANY-TO-MANY MERGE:([m].[annonsid])=([m3].[annonsid2]), RESIDUAL:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[annonsid] as [m].[annonsid]=[MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[annonsid2] as [m3].[annonsid2]))
                                 |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([m].[annonsid]), ORDER BY:([m].[annonsid] ASC))
                                 |    |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[NonClusteredIndex-20121229-133152] AS [m]), ORDERED FORWARD)
                                 |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([m3].[annonsid2]), ORDER BY:([m3].[annonsid2] ASC))
                                      |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDatabase].[dbo].[Matching_IDs].[NonClusteredIndex-20121229-133207] AS [m3]), ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: What indexes do you have defined on the table? An index `(annonsid2,annonsid)` may be a good option.

Comment: I have a clustered index of both columns, and one non-clustered for every column (2)

Comment: Where does the query plan say time is taken?

Comment: Well, it takes about 2 seconds from when i Press run until it starts to show results, but it doesn't mean the query is that fast right?, cause when I just do a Count(m.annonsid) instead of getting all the records, its taking around 1 minute.

Comment: Could you append query plan to the question?

Comment: On which both? Have you composite PK?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my execution plan: [link](http://www.supportcaddy.com/executionplan.png)

Comment: This is Estimated execution plan. Use `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` to get execution plan and post here.

Comment: ok, running it now, posting when done. Thanks!

Comment: Runned execution plan (1 minute), [link](http://www.supportcaddy.com/executionplan2.png)

Comment: Nothing new. Have you set show text plan option? And in your estimated  plan diagram i haven't see where clause?

Comment: ok sorry, a bit new to this, here it comes: [link](http://www.supportcaddy.com/debug.txt)

Comment: The query test does not match the execution plan. Please make them consistent.

Comment: it does now, it was just count(*) instead of selecting columns.

Comment: just for a try SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Matching_IDs AS m
  INNER JOIN Matching_IDs AS m2
     ON m.annonsid2 = m2.annonsid
Where Exist(Select * from  Matching_IDs  m3 where m2.annonsid2 = m3.annonsid AND m.annonsid = m3.annonsid2)

Comment: What does "who can swap with who" mean? Could you provide some sample data please, and describe what it MEANS? When you are not just doing `Count(*)`, what columns are you pulling? Without truly understanding the full context of what you're doing, our brains cannot activate effectively to be sure we're giving you the best answer. Sometimes, answers that you couldn't have imagined are possible, but only when the experts are fully aware of the whole problem space rather than just the tiny slice you've presented.

Comment: Erik E, I understand. What I am having is a table with 2 ids (id1, id2), this is id of an ad and points that id1 is interested in swapping with id2. This way I can build direct swaps between two ad's (2 ids), triangle swaps like a triangle with three corners where id1 gets id2, who gets id3 who gets id1. same in a rectangle swap, id1 > id2 > id3 > id4 > id1. Do you understand?

Comment: Please tag with the @ symbol or people will not get notified. Why is swapping always forward--for every `id,id2` pair is `id2,id` in the table? What are you doing with the results? If you have ads 1, 2, 3, and 4 you have rows `1,2`, `2,3`, `3,4` and `4,1` (right?) but why not `2,4` or `4,2`? Something here is triggering my instincts that there could be a different way to accomplish your purpose.

Comment: @infinity1975 I wish you would answer, this sounds like a fun/interesting puzzle.

Comment: 1.5 million is nothing. We need a number that self joins a 40 million rows (and counting) table. Obviously it's not working too well. :/

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

Try two indexes (annonsid,annonsid2) and (annonsid2,annonsid)

Have you tried a column store index? It makes the table read only but it might improve performance.

Also, some variations of the query could help. Examples:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Matching_IDs AS m
  INNER JOIN Matching_IDs AS m2
     ON m.annonsid2 = m2.annonsid
  INNER JOIN Matching_IDs AS m3
     ON m2.annonsid2 = m3.annonsid
where m.annonsid = m3.annonsid2
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Matching_IDs AS m, Matching_IDs AS m2, Matching_IDs AS m3
where m2.annonsid2 = m3.annonsid
  and m.annonsid2 = m2.annonsid
  and m.annonsid = m3.annonsid2
```

Did you check the CPU/IO-Load? If IO-Load is high, then the server is not crunching numbers but swapping => more RAM solves the problem.

How fast is this query?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Matching_IDs AS m
  INNER JOIN Matching_IDs AS m2
     ON m.annonsid2 = m2.annonsid
```

If this is very fast but adding the next join slows thing down then you propably need more RAM.

Comment: #1 and #2 is similair (22 seconds) same as my normal query, i managed to use a distinct table which went down from 1 minute to 22 seconds. The 3rd query is very fast, 2 seconds. I have 8gb ram.

Comment: Actually what I really want is to remove the 1 to 1 id table, but I have no clue on how I can know which ad matches which in an easy way. I thought about having alot of bigint's and using bitwise and between the ads. This is narrowing the search down to 15.000 ads (rows) instead of 1,5 million. BUT, the end result will anyway be 15 million so it might not be worth it.

Comment: What do you mean by 1 to 1 id table? Regarding performance: I just did a test on my laptop. Counting 6 mio rows takes a while (20 secs) and so I doubt you can get much faster.

Comment: It's a table with 2 id's pointing left to right, id1 wants id2.

Comment: How about adding `and m.AnnonId != m.AnnonId2`? Do this with all three tables (m, m1, m2). It might help a bit, but they get sorted out anyway, as you said.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already indexed this quite well. You can try converting the hash to a merge join by adding the right multi-column index, but it won't give you the desired speedup of 60x.

I think this index would be on `annonsid, annonsid2` although I might have made a mistake here.

It would be nice to materialize all of this but indexed views do not support self-joins. You can try to materialize this query (unaggregated) into a new table. Whenever you execute DML against the base table, also update the second table (using either application logic or triggers). That would allow you to query blazingly fast.

Answer (score 1):

You should make this query a bit more separated. I think first you should create a table, where you can store the primary key + annonsid, annonsid2 -*if annosid is not the primary key itself*.

```
DECLARE @AnnonsIds TABLE
(
primaryKey int,
-- if you need later more info from the original rows like captions  
-- AND it is not (just) the annonsid
annonsid int,
annonsid2 int
)
```

If you declare a table, and you have index on this column, it is quite fast to get the specified rows by the `WHERE annonsid = @annonsid OR annonsid2 = @annosid`

After the first step you have a much smaller (I guess), and "thin" table to work with. Then you just have to use the joins here or make a temp table and a CTE on it.

I think it should be faster, depending on the selectivity of the condition in the `WHERE`, of yourse if 1.1 million rows fits in it, then it does not make sense, but if just a couple hundred or tousend, then you should give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You could denormalize the data by adding a table `RelatedIds` with `AnnonsId`, `RelatedAnnonId` and `Distance`.  For every value of `AnnonsId` the table would contains rows for each `RelatedAnnonId` and the number of relations that need to be traversed to reach it, aka `Distance`.  Triggers on the existing `MatchingIds` table would maintain the new table with some configured maximum value for `Distance`, e.g. 3 to handle rectangular shares.  Index the table on (`AnnonsId`, `Distance`).

*Edit:* An index on (`Distance`, `AnnonsId`) will allow you to quickly find rows that have enough related entries to form a particular shape.  Adding a column for `MaxDistance` may be useful if you want to be able to exclude rows based on, for example, having a triangular but *not* rectangular relationship.

The new query would `inner join RelatedIds as RI on RI.AnnonsId = m.AnnonsId and RI.Distance <= @MaxDistance` with the desired "shape" dictating the value of `@MaxDistance`.

It should provide much better performance on the `select`.  Downsides are another table with a large number of rows and overhead of the triggers when altering the `MatchingIds` table.

Example: There are two entries in `Matching_IDs`: (1,2) and (2,3).
The new table would contain 3 entries:
1-> 2: distance = 1
1-> 3: distance = 2 (it takes one intermediate 'node' to go from 1 to 3)
2-> 3: distance = 1

adding one more entry to the matching ids (3,1) would result in another entry:
1-> 1: distance = 3

And voilá: You found a triangle (distance=3).

Now, to find all triangles, simply do this:

```
select * 
  from RelatedIds 
 where AnnonsId=RelatedAnnonId 
   and Distance=3
```

Comment: this was way to complex for me to understand :D, What I already have is a table relatedids, this is the table "Matching_IDs" who have (annonsid, annonsid2), What I dont understand is the "Distance" and how to get it?, and what the triggers will do.

Comment: The problem persist I think?, the problem is the performance, not to create the outcome. This trigger is just the same as using my query by providing an id making it run on only that id, and then save the result in a second table. Am I wrong?

Comment: @infinity1975 - The difference is that the trigger divides the heavy lifting into a relatively small amount of work every time the base table is changed.  A downside is that the work is always performed, even if you never query for "shapes".  The upside is that the "shapes" query should be much faster.

Comment: Yes, I have a solution for this, except the distance parameter. I have one table for directswaps and one for triangleswaps.

Comment: I have one table for directswaps and one for triangleswaps. But I was out for a solution making the first select faster. It's still a time consuming task.

Comment: @infinity1975 - I keep getting the feeling that you don't understand triggers.  The basic idea is much like maintaining a bank account balance.  You can either sum up every transaction for an account from the beginning of time to determine the current balance or you can take a little extra time when each transaction occurs to maintain a separate "current balance" field for the account.  The first approach is nicely normalized, but the performance will suffer over time.  The second approach spreads the workload out over time so that the performance of querying a balance remains constant.

Comment: @infinity1975 - Your comment re: having tables for direct and triangle swaps is unclear to me.  How do you keep those tables current?

Comment: By just "precalcing" them when an ad changes. It's similair to trigger but I do it in my c# code.

Answer (score 0):

1 - change select `Count(*)` to `Count(1)`  or  `Count(id)`

2 - Write  `set Nocount on`  at the first of your Stored procedure or at the first of your Query

3 - Use index on `annonsid` , `annonsid2`

4 - Having your Indexes after the primary key in your Table

Comment: 1- there is no difference between `count(*)` and count(1)` etc. I tested it.

Comment: Correct. There is a difference when it comes to WHAT to count. But this does not apply to infinity1975's problem, as far as I can see it. But +1 for pointing that out.